# How to group Yeoman`s output`s all scripts,images to custom folder

Tags: javascript, workflow, yeoman

I want to integrate Yeoman workflow with my python backend, I used to put all minimized/reversion scripts, css, images into "static" folder for nginx cache usage.

Now what I want to do is change Yeoman`s output structure, put "bower_component","images","scripts","styles" to "dist/static" folder, and keep else html or tpl in "dist" folder.

I tried to change Grunt configuration, but failed, Here is my changes:

1. Change file structure in "app" folder like what I want, update index.html and requirejs.
2. Update file structure in Gruntfiles.js according to "app" folder.
3. Change all 'yeoman.dist' related in Gruntfiles.js as I want, put scripts, css, images to 'static' folder.

   ```
   useminPrepare: {
       html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
       options: {
           dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/static'
       }
   },

   usemin: {
       html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
       css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/static/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
       options: {
           dirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/static']
       }
   },

   imagemin: {
       dist: {
           files: [{
               expand: true,
               cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/static/images',
               src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg}',
               dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/static/images'
           }]
       }
   },

   cssmin: {
       dist: {
           files: {
               '<%= yeoman.dist %>/static/styles/main.css': [
                   '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                   '<%= yeoman.app %>/static/styles/{,*/}*.css'
               ]
           }
       }
   },

   htmlmin: {
       dist: {
           options: {
               /*removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
               // https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin/issues/44
               //collapseWhitespace: true,
               collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
               removeAttributeQuotes: true,
               removeRedundantAttributes: true,
               useShortDoctype: true,
               removeEmptyAttributes: true,
               removeOptionalTags: true*/
           },
           files: [{
               expand: true,
               cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
               src: '*.html',
               dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
           }]
       }
   },

   copy: {
       dist: {
           files: [{
               expand: true,
               dot: true,
               cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
               dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
               src: [
                   '*.{ico,txt}',
                   '.htaccess',
                   'static/images/{,*/}*.{webp,gif}'
               ]
           }]
       }
   },

   bower: {
       all: {
           rjsConfig: '<%= yeoman.app %>/static/scripts/main.js'
       }
   },

   jst: {
       options: {
           amd: true
       },
       compile: {
           files: {
               '.tmp/scripts/templates.js': ['<%= yeoman.app  %>/static/scripts/templates/*.ejs']
           }
       }
   },

   rev: {
       dist: {
           files: {
               src: [
                   '<%= yeoman.dist %>/static/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                   '<%= yeoman.dist %>/static/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                   '<%= yeoman.dist %>/static/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp}',
                   '<%= yeoman.dist %>/static/styles/fonts/*'
               ]
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   });

But the outputs can not Update the HTML to reference our concat/min/revved script files, and output " bower_components" folder`s path have problems.Anyone want to take look at source code, check on [Github](https://github.com/Wangchao0721/YeomanCustomOutputDemo).

And another way is I change all nginx configurations to use those four folders instead of static folder.Can someone tell me what best practice for my requirement? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed this by two steps:

1. Change 'useminPrepare task`s 'dest' to '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
2. Change 'build:js' in app/index.html to 'static/scripts/...' to tell 'usemin' where to copy js to 'static folder'

So now I can put all min/ugly/reversion scripts, images, styles, bower_components to 'dest/static' folder for nginx cache usage.Check the project update on [Github](https://github.com/Wangchao0721/YeomanCustomOutputDemo).

But to automately generate this kind of project, the best way may custom Yeoman generator instead of changing [generator_backbone](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-backbone)`s output, I will try it later.